# How can I align one navbar item to either end depending on language selection?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I have a div that contains list components. What I want to do is to position the last li component to the end of that div.

The webpage has 2 versions , Arabic and English , so the dir is changed based on selected language

[image]

```css
#navbarSupportedContent .nav-item {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: 800;
  border-right: 1px solid #01154D;
  padding: 10px 24px;
}

.navbar {
  padding: 0px !important;
}

 .navbar {
  position: relative;
  min-height: 40px !important;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  border: none !important;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-zCbKRCUGaJDkqS1kPbPd7TveP5iyJE0EjAuZQTgFLD2ylzuqKfdKlfG/eSrtxUkn" crossorigin="anonymous">

<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-primary sticky-top" style="">
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse justify-content-center" id="navbarSupportedContent">
    <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto" style="/* float:inherit; */">
      <li class="nav-item active">
        <a class="nav-link" href="/webcenter/portal/ROPInternalPortal/pages_en">
          <span id="submenu1">Home</span>
        </a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item ">
        <a class="nav-link nav-hover-fix" href="/webcenter/portal/ROPInternalPortal/pages_employeetools">
          <span id="submenu1">Employee Tools</span>
        </a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item ">
        <div class="dropdown show">
          <a style="color:#e6ecf2;" aria-expanded="false" aria-haspopup="true" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#" id="dropdownMenuLink" role="button">MEDIA CENTER</a>
          <div aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuLink" class="dropdown-menu">
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="/webcenter/portal/ROPInternalPortal/pages_mediacenter/photogallery">PHOTO GALLERY</a>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="/webcenter/portal/ROPInternalPortal/pages_mediacenter/news1">NEWS</a>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="/webcenter/portal/ROPInternalPortal/pages_mediacenter/newpage">ROP MAGAZINE</a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item ">
        <a class="nav-link" href="/webcenter/portal/ROPInternalPortal/pages_documents">
          <span id="submenu1">Documents</span>
        </a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item"><a data-afr-tlen="7" id="T:arabic2" class="nav-link xej" style="font-size: initial;" onclick="this.focus();return false;" data-afr-fcs="true" href="#"><span style="">العربية</span>
    <i aria-hidden="true" class="fa fa-language"></i></a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item" style=""><span id="T:wcLogoutLink:spacesActionPGL" class="x1a"><a data-afr-tlen="0" id="T:wcLogoutLink:logoutLink" title="Log out of WebCenter Portal" class="nav-linkglyphicon glyphicon-log-out xf0 " 
    " onclick="this.focus();return false;" data-afr-fcs="true" href="#"></a></span>
      </li>
    </ul>
    
    <span id="T:search2" class="x1a">
      <div class="navbar-form navbar-left visible-xs" id="searchxs"><div id="T:searchbox2" class="x131" aria-live="polite"><div style="display:none"><a id="T:searchbox2:_afrCommandDelegate" class="xej" onclick="this.focus();return false;" data-afr-fcs="true" href="#"></a></div></div>
      </div>
    </span>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: Please format your code properly and put it in a snippet demo using the editor. No one likes working with walls of text.

Comment: If you're able to update to Bootstrap 5, it provides _start_ and _end_ directions instead of left and right. This would suit youwell.

Comment: Your list seems to have a problem near the end (extra quotation marks).

Answer (score 0):

Use `display: flex` and `margin`: left/right set to `auto` for your last child LI (using the `:last-child` selector) - depending on `dir="rtl"` attribute exists on the element or document

```css
.navbar {
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
  display: flex;
  background: gold;
}

.navbar > * { padding: 0.5em 1em; }

.navbar > *:last-child {
  margin-left: auto;
}

[dir="rtl"] .navbar > *:last-child,
.navbar[dir="rtl"] > *:last-child {
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: 0;
}
```

```html
<ul class="navbar">
  <li>1</li>
  <li>2</li>
  <li>3</li>
  <li>4</li>
  <li>5</li>
</ul>

<ul class="navbar" dir="rtl">
  <li>1</li>
  <li>2</li>
  <li>3</li>
  <li>4</li>
  <li>5</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

I try to solve in vanillajs. Maybe you can adapt this solution in your question.

I think `margin-inline-start` is what is you looking for.

```css
.element {
  display: flex;
  background: #fff;
  box-shadow: 0 3px 10px 0 rgba(#000, 0.1);
  padding: 1rem;
  margin-bottom: 2.5rem;
  justify-content: space-between;
  border: 1px solid #000
}

.item {
  padding: 1rem 1.4rem;
  background: #673AB7;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 24px;
}
.item:last-child {
  margin-inline-start: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">  
  <p style="margin-bottom: 0.5rem;">Left to Right (LTR)</p>
  <div class="element">
    <div class="item">1</div>
    <div class="item">2</div>
    <div class="item">3</div>
  </div>
  
  <p style="margin-bottom: 0.5rem;">Right to Left (RTL)</p>
  <div class="element" dir="rtl">
    <div class="item">1</div>
    <div class="item">2</div>
    <div class="item">3</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

##### Use Flexbox to position the elements at the left and the last one at the right

Just what you have to do is added the code below
Because you are using all the bootstrap class so add a new class to 2 div container

```css
# New Class
.Nav-container{
 display: flex;
 # Or without flex add only below property
 justify-content: flex-start;
```

Added another class for the last nav-item or a pseudo class

```css
 .last-item{
  justify-self: flex-end;
 }
  or
 .nav-item:nth-of-type(5){
   justify-self: flex-end;
 }
```

Comment: Bootstrap already provides [classes for those properties](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.6/utilities/flex/#enable-flex-behaviors). There's no need for custom CSS here.

Comment: Is my answer working

Comment: I have no idea. Perhaps if you'd built a demo using the editor we could see.

Comment: hello , i tried but it is not working

Comment: Why hardcode  `5` in `.nav-item:nth-of-type(5)`? That's error prone. Simply use `:last-child`